# Is there any non polymorphic base class reference in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class Base {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base b = new Derived();
        b.printName();
    }
    public void printName() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
    }

}

class Derived extends Base {

}
```

the code above prints the derived class name. how can I make it print the base class name. Keep in mind that the code is used to classify the question. I don't actually need to print the class name. I need the `this` in `printName` be exactly the type of `Base` **even in a `Derived` instance**. It's has not be the name `this`, anything do the work would be OK. Is it possible?

To further specify the question. Some third party library I used in base class didn't get their job done in Derived class instance. And I figure it out that's because they called getClass() of the `this` I passed in but didn't get the `Class<?>` they expected. How can I workaround this?

Comment: Why don't you just ask for `instanceof Base`? Although in general that indicates a wonky design to begin with. Also, funky to ask for a child class in the super class unless it's specifically a factory (or just a test, which is probably the case this time).

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the root class is always `Object`? So from `Derived`'s perspective, how would you specify when to stop climbing up the inheritance chain?

Comment: @singhakash OP wants it to be a `Derived`, but reported as a `Base`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only thing you can do is

```
System.out.println(Base.class);
```

Some GUIs might even auto-rename those when renaming the Base class.

Comment: And by "GUI" you mean "IDE"?

Comment: Sure. And while you're at it, mark the `printName()` method as `final` to keep subclasses from overriding it.

Comment: I can't do this. Some third party library I used in base class didn't get their job done in Derived class instance. And I figure it out that because they called getClass() and didn't receive the Class they expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, since Java methods are always virtual (those you can override, that is).

See also: [Are all method in java implictly virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752343/are-all-method-in-java-implictly-virtual)

Comment: This is not about Java methods being virtual. This is because OP's using `this`.